# Если кодировка сайта и функции (в контроллере) в разных кодировках…

Tags: php, кодировка, kohana, фреймворк

Фрэймверк «kohana»,
в «bootstrap.php» установлено “setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.utf-8');”
В контроллере, хочу получить, день недели (буквами)

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'rus_RUS');        
$date = '2013-01-01';
$utf8 = strftime("%A, %d/%m/%Y", strtotime($date));
echo"utf8 = $utf8";
```

выводит:

```
utf8 = �������, 01/01/2013
```

функция возвращает результат в «win1251»
пришлось:

```
$textwin1251 = iconv('windows-1251', 'UTF-8', $ut8);
echo $textwin1251;
```

выводит «вторник» - все ОК.
**Вопрос**:
Можно ли обойтись как-нибудь без «iconv»? Иначе терзает смутное сомнение, что что-то тут не чисто.

Comment: В meta тегах HTML задайте кодировку.

Comment: пробовал, тогда остальной текст преобразуется в "абру-кодабру"

Comment: Полагаю, это от того, что сами файлы в кодировке win-1251. Если вы их перекодируете в utf-8, проблема решена. При создании проекта надо внимательно проверять, чтобы все было в utf-8